# Getting error in upload php

Tags: php

I am getting this error in my code now:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/upload.php on line 83

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/upload.php on line 84
```

here is my line of code:

```
79.dbConnect();
80. $SQL="SELECT fileId FROM upload WHERE fileName='".$result."'";
81. //echo $SQL;
82. $rs=mysql_query($SQL);
83. echo mysql_num_rows($rs);
84. if(mysql_num_rows($rs)!=0){
85.     $extension=strrchr($result,'.');
86.     $result=str_replace($extension,time(),$result);
87.     $result=$result.$extension;
88. }
89. return $result;
90.}
```

Thanks.

This is also another error I am getting..

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/upload/tmb-desert.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/upload.php on line 55

Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/upload/desert.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/snorris/upload.php on line 56

   53. imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y);
    54. if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"jpeg"))){
    55.     imagejpeg($dst_img,"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/upload/".$thumbFilename);
    56. imagejpeg($src_img,"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/upload/".$filename);
        }
  57.   if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"png"))){
        58. imagepng($dst_img,"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/upload/".$thumbFilename);
        59. imagepng($src_img,"/home/valerie2/public_html/elinkswap/upload/".$filename);
        }
```

Sorry everyone I am still learning the file upload stuff.

Comment: @micha it could be more than just a db connection that failed. It could have to do with the table, field or values contained with the sql.

Comment: where is the upload code and the msg is clear make sure that you are on the rights paths :)

Comment: i am woundering if I am crossing paths somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have something wrong with your query 
try this and but back the error msg

```
 82  $rs=mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

The above code will terminate the script with the error msg from the SQL if exists

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_error() & mysql_errno() to extract the error details:

```
$rs=mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

A better option is to use a db class that can handle these errors for you, allowing you to trap & handle db errors rather then simply killing the script.